# How to call a function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function and that function is present in two JS files. Both files are loading on a page load. That why that function is calling 2 times. I need to call that one time from any file. Once it called from any file then it wont call again. I need to keep that function in both files, cant remove from any. Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: You really should post the code of the function and the way that it's called.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is to not duplicate your code.  What exactly is preventing this from happening?

Comment: here is a rough demo https://jsfiddle.net/5ez2968w/

Comment: Doesn't the first function override the second?
Anyway I would try something like `var newFunc = oldFunc; newFunc()`

Comment: no its not overriding. I want the chat function should call only once from function one or two. Anyone

Comment: Your issue sounds like it is best fixed by restructuring your code so that a function is not duplicated and not called more than once for any given page.  Sure, there are ways to hack a solution (one of which has already been provided), but those are hacks and NOT the best design pattern.  Properly structured code has an organized set of initialization for each page and can control things so something is not called more than once.  Or, your function examines state to see if things have already been initialized such that it does not need to repeat the work.

Comment: Agreed @jfriend00 but unfortunately I cant rewrite the code in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As multiple commenters have pointed out, you really should restructure your code so that you're not duplicating it.

That said, there are possible hacks. If you really can't remove it you could find a way to make your function idempotent (at least in the sense that it can be called repeatedly to no adverse effect). You could use a boolean flag stored somewhere that flips from false to true. Then in your function you just guard your operations with that flag.

```
var has_been_called = false;

function run() {
  if (!has_been_called) {
    //the rest of your code
    has_been_called = true;
  }
}
```

On the first call to run the code will execute, and successive calls will not.

Comment: can you pls share a fiddle?

Comment: @Bryce77 It's just some simple pseudocode. But if you have a specific question regarding my suggestion then I'd be happy to elaborate.